# class AngularfireModule is not an angular module

Tags: angular, firebase, angular8

I tried to use firebase in my Angular app:

```
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
...

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ...
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig, 'my-app')
    ],
    ...
})
```

However, I got an error:

> class **AngularfireModule** is not an Angular Module

and

> class **AngularFireDatabaseModule** is not an Angular Module

I don't know if this is the correct way to use Firebase with Angular 8, or if there is another way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to download `@angular/fire` not `angularfire2`. angularfire2 is an old version of `@angular/fire`.

Angular 6+ or 7/8+ command `ng add @angular/fire`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Mises, angularfire2 is an older version, current angular firebase commands are: 
To install firebase:
npm install firebase or  npm install firebase @angular/fire 
Now in app.module.ts

```
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire'
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from '@angular/fire/database'
```

Also, add these two modules in imports array below in app.module.ts